# Alternative to border-radius for horizontal+vertical values on a div

Tags: html, css, border-radius

I'm working on a specific website called toyhou.se in which horizontal+vertical border-radius is not available and I can only use inline CSS.
I made a code for a Tamagotchi (egg) shaped pagedoll than requieres such function and I'm looking for an alternative way of creating the same effect. The css I used on my div is: `border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 60% 40% 40%`.

[Correct shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Io0.png): How it looks like on th.circlejourney.net where I always code to use in ToyHouse. Most of the settings of this page are the same as ToyHouse but it can happen that some whitelisted code is available here but not on the other.

[Incorrect shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbmDl.png): How the code looks on toyhou.se

Full code:

```
<div class="container p-2">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-auto overflow-hidden d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center" style="width: 167px; height: 202px; border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 60% 40% 40%; border: 6px solid #673388; background: url(https://f2.toyhou.se/file/f2-toyhou-se/images/33482918_y7Ci5NMXmOcA865.png) no-repeat center; background-size: cover">
            <div style="opacity: 0.5; color: #8f49bb; margin-top: 10px;">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cloud fa-rotate-180 fa-3x" style=" vertical-align: top;"></i>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cloud fa-rotate-180 fa-2x" style="margin-left: -10px; vertical-align: top;"></i>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cloud fa-rotate-180 fa-3x" style="margin-left: -10px; vertical-align: top;"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-2 p-1" style="width: 75px; height: 75px; border: 3px solid #673388 ; background: url(https://f2.toyhou.se/file/f2-toyhou-se/images/33306534_A5htslLMboAMqI3.png); background-size: cover"><img src="https://f2.toyhou.se/file/f2-toyhou-se/images/14048794_mz7myAcDurhTBqb.png?1661809559"></div>
            <div class="font-weight-bold" style="color: #673388;">Fideo</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div style="width: 17px; height: 17px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #8f49bb; border: 3px solid #673388;"></div>
                <div class="mt-2" style="width: 17px; height: 17px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #8f49bb; border: 3px solid #673388; margin-left: 12px; margin-right: 12px"></div>
                <div style="width: 17px; height: 17px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #8f49bb; border: 3px solid #673388;"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="opacity: 0.5; color: #8f49bb; margin-top: -5px">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cloud fa-3x"></i>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cloud fa-2x" style="margin-left: -10px"></i>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cloud fa-3x" style="margin-left: -10px"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using an image for the shaped background but the code doesn't work the same as how I wanted it to look.
Using `-webkit-border-radius: 50%/50% ; border-radius: 40%/60%;` didn't achieve the same effect either.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```html
<div class="container p-2">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-auto overflow-hidden d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center" style="width: 167px; height: 202px; border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 60% 40% 40%; border: 6px solid #673388; background: url(https://f2.toyhou.se/file/f2-toyhou-se/images/33482918_y7Ci5NMXmOcA865.png) no-repeat center; background-size: cover; display: flex; align-items: center;justify-content: center;">
      <div style="opacity: 0.5; color: #8f49bb; margin-top: 10px;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-cloud fa-rotate-180 fa-3x" style=" vertical-align: top;"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-cloud fa-rotate-180 fa-2x" style="margin-left: -10px; vertical-align: top;"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-cloud fa-rotate-180 fa-3x" style="margin-left: -10px; vertical-align: top;"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-2 p-1" style="margin-bottom:10px;display:flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;position: absolute; width: 75px; height: 75px; border: 3px solid #673388 ; background: url(https://f2.toyhou.se/file/f2-toyhou-se/images/33306534_A5htslLMboAMqI3.png); background-size: cover">
        <img src="https://f2.toyhou.se/file/f2-toyhou-se/images/14048794_mz7myAcDurhTBqb.png?1661809559" height="60px">
      </div>
      <div class="font-weight-bold" style="color: #673388;margin-top:100px; position:absolute">Fideo</div>

      <div style="margin:150px 0px 0px 0px;position:absolute;width: 17px; height: 17px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #8f49bb; border: 3px solid #673388;"></div>
      <div class="mt-2" style="margin:120px 75px 0px 0px;position:absolute;width: 17px; height: 17px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #8f49bb; border: 3px solid #673388; "></div>
      <div style="margin:120px -75px 0px 0px;position:absolute; width: 17px; height: 17px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #8f49bb; border: 3px solid #673388;"></div>

      <div style="opacity: 0.5; color: #8f49bb; margin-top: -5px">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-cloud fa-3x"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-cloud fa-2x" style="margin-left: -10px"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-cloud fa-3x" style="margin-left: -10px"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/solid.min.css" />
```

Comment: Your comment doesn't use a border-radius alternative for the egg shape, so it's not useful to me. My problem is I that can't use border-radius with two values (horizontal+vertical) on a specific page.